# Set local: true as default for form_with in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm working on a project where we won't be using ajax calls for submitting the forms, so I need to put `local: true` in every form in the project, as indicated in the rails [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with):

`:local - By default form submits are remote and unobstrusive XHRs. Disable remote submits with local: true.`

Is there any way to set the local option as true by default?

We're using Rails 5 `form_with` helper like this:

```
<%= form_with(model: @user, local: true) do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Not really. Had to set `local: true` to every form

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you've stated it can be set on a per form basis with `local: true`. However it can be set it globally use the configuration option `[form_with_generates_remote_forms][1]`. This setting determines whether form_with generates remote forms or not. It defaults to true.

Where to put this configuration? Rails offers [four standard spots](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#locations-for-initialization-code) to place configurations like this. But you probably want this configuration in all enviroments (i.e. development, production, ...). So either set it in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/action_view.rb
Rails.application.config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms = false
```

Or maybe more commonly set in config/application.rb.

```
# config/application.rb
module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # [...]

    config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms = false
  end
end
```

Comment: For posterity: This is a better solution than the one I suggested above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492613/1146473)

Comment: Updated with more info on where to put the config (as per ecoologic's answer).

Answer (score 12):

Consider overriding the `form_with` method:

```
# form_helper.rb
def form_with(options)
  options[:local] = true
  super options
end
```

That should solve it for every form in your application.

Answer (score 12):

The Rails configurations can be set in `config/application.rb` file.

```
module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # [...]

    config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms = false
  end
end
```

Guy C answer is good, but it's more idiomatic to put all config in this file rather than a separate initializer; That's where most of the Rails dev would expect it.

Note that this would spell disaster if you put it `config/development.rb` only or other env specific files.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. +1 to changing configuration in the location where most developers would expect it.